# Detecting Trying to get property of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

please help me.

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /Data/oa-dev4/resources/views/surat_tugas/list_surat_tugas/table_total.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   /Data/oa-dev4/resources/views/surat_tugas/list_surat_tugas/table_total.blade.php)

```
<div class="caption">
    <i class="fa fa-table font-blue-oa"></i>
    <span class="caption-subject font-blue-oa sbold uppercase">Rekap Biaya dan Pelaksanaan Surat Tugas Tahun {{$tahun_st}}</span>
</div>
<div class="portlet-body">
    <table class="table table-datatable table-bordered table-checkable table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="heading">
                <th class='hidden'></th>
                <th class="text-center"> </th>
                <th class="text-center"> Jumlah Hari </th>
                <th class="text-center"> Transport </th>
                <th class="text-center"> Penginapan</th>
                <th class="text-center"> Uang Harian</th>
                <th class="text-center"> Jumlah</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class='sbold'>Total</td>
                @if($rekap->jumlah_hari)
                <td class="text-right">{{$rekap->jumlah_hari}} Hari</td>
                @else
                    <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                @endif
                @if(Helper::convert_rupiah($rekap->transport))
                    <td class="text-right">{{Helper::convert_number($rekap->transport)}}</td>
                @else
                    <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                @endif
                @if(Helper::convert_rupiah($rekap->penginapan))
                <td class="text-right">{{Helper::convert_number($rekap->penginapan)}}</td>
                @else
                    <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                @endif
                @if(Helper::convert_rupiah($rekap->harian))
                <td class="text-right">{{Helper::convert_number($rekap->harian)}}</td>
                @else
                    <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                @endif
                @if(Helper::convert_rupiah($rekap->transport) || Helper::convert_rupiah($rekap->transport)|| Helper::convert_rupiah($rekap->transport))
                <td class="text-right">{{Helper::convert_number($rekap->transport + $rekap->harian + $rekap->penginapan)}}</td>
                @else
                    <td class="text-right"> - </td>
                @endif
            <tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the data you are getting in $rekap variable.
Else use the isset like this isset($rekap->jumlah_hari)

Comment: give the screenshot of dd($rekap)

Comment: Please provide controller code also

Answer (score 0):

The following error means you are accessing a value that is not an object.

> Trying to get property of non-object

If the `$rekap` variable is an array then you have to convert it into an object and then access is in you blade template.

Comment: another way is, access the variable as array.